# Page stops loading after using component selector in another html file Angular 5

Tags: angular, components, angular5, image-upload

I am trying to add image uplaod on the registration form and create a component of upload in which i will place my upload button html.

I created the component inside app/shared/forms/image-upload/upload.

Here is the upload.component.ts file code:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { UploadEvent, UploadFile } from '../../../file-drop';
import { SortingService } from '../../../services/sorting.service';
import { FileService } from '../../../../api';
import { File } from '../../../../api/models';

import { NotificationsService } from '../../../../shared/notifications';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
  selector: 'repo-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss']
})
export class UploadComponent{

  @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() file: File;
  @Output()
  public onImageChange: EventEmitter<File> = new EventEmitter<File>();

  public imageList: UploadFile[];
  private imageMimeTypes: string[] = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private sortingService: SortingService, private fileService: FileService, private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
    this.imageList = this.sortingService.list;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.parentFormGroup.addControl('images', this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required));
  }
  /**
   * add image to the file uploader
   *
   * @param event
   */
  handleImageAdd(event: UploadEvent) {
    for (let i = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
      let formControl = new FormControl();
      this.images.push(formControl);

      let uploadFile = event.files[i];
      let error: any;
      if (!this.imageMimeTypes.includes(uploadFile.file.type)) {
        error = error || {};
        error.mimes = true;
      }

      // Size is given in bytes
      if (uploadFile.file.size > 10000000) {
        error = error || {};
        error.max = true
      }

      if (error) {
        formControl.setErrors(error);
      }
    }

    this.checkFormValidity();
    this.sortingService.addAll(event.files);

    this.handleImageSave(event);
  }

  handleImageSave(event) {
    //iterate through each uploaded image, save it and remove it from the file dropper
    this.imageList.forEach((uploadFile, index, imageList) => {
      let fileFormData = new FormData();
      fileFormData.append('file', uploadFile.file);

      this.fileService.save(fileFormData)
        .subscribe(
        (file) => {
          this.notificationsService.success('Image saved successfully!');
          imageList.splice(index);
          this.onImageChange.emit(file);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.status === 422) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
        );
    });
  }

  removeImage(index: number) {
    this.sortingService.remove(index);
    this.images.removeAt(index);
    this.checkFormValidity();
  }

  private checkFormValidity() {
    if (this.images.length > 0) {
      this.images.setValidators([]);
    } else {
      this.images.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
    this.images.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  get images() {
    return this.parentFormGroup.get('images') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

Now the issue is that when I am using `<repo-upload></repo-upload>` inside my `signup-form.component.html` file then the page don't show any thing.

When I look into the console of the page I am getting an error. See the screenshot:[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue. I am trying from last 1 day to fix it.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add this component in app.module.ts file. After adding it inside the app.module.ts file i am getting error:

```
Uncaught Error: Type UploadComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and AppModule! Please consider moving UploadComponent to a higher module that imports SharedModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes UploadComponent then import that NgModule in SharedModule and AppModule.
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaModule, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RecaptchaFormsModule } from 'ng-recaptcha/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
import { DeviceDetectorModule } from 'ngx-device-detector';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { ApiModule, ProfileService, PropertyService } from './api';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthModule } from './auth';
import { DummyComponent } from './dummy.component';
import { InterceptorsModule } from './interceptors';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared';
import { UserModule } from './user';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './user/signup-form/signup-form.component';
import { PropertySearchFormComponent } from './property/property-search-form/property-search-form.component';
import { PropertyViewComponent } from './property/property-view/property-view.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { SearchResultlistComponent } from './search/search-resultlist/search-resultlist.component';
import { SearchResultComponent } from './search/search-result/search-result.component';
import { ProfileSearchFormComponent } from './profile/profile-search-form/profile-search-form.component';
import { ProfileViewComponent } from './profile/profile-view/profile-view.component';
import { ProfileEditComponent } from './profile/profile-edit/profile-edit.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { InquiriesComponent } from './inquiries/inquiries.component';
import { InquiryItemComponent } from './inquiries/inquiry-item/inquiry-item.component';
import { PropertyEditComponent } from './property/property-edit/property-edit.component';
import { PropertyComponent } from './property/property.component';
import { InquiryItemFormComponent } from './inquiries/inquiry-item-form/inquiry-item-form.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './user/account/account.component';
import { AccountViewComponent } from './user/account/account-view/account-view.component';
import { AccountEditComponent } from './user/account/account-edit/account-edit.component';
import { PasswordResetComponent } from './user/password-reset/password-reset.component';
import { PasswordResetSendComponent } from './user/password-reset/password-reset-send/password-reset-send.component';
import { PasswordResetSubmitComponent } from './user/password-reset/password-reset-submit/password-reset-submit.component';
import { UserAuthentificationComponent } from './user/user-authentification/user-authentification.component';
import { GlobalNotificationsDirective } from './global-notifications/global-notifications.directive';
import { SearchInfoWindowComponent } from './search/search-info/search-info-window/search-info-window.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
import { TenantDetailComponent } from './profile/tenant-detail/tenant-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SignupFormComponent,
    DummyComponent,
    PropertyComponent,
    PropertySearchFormComponent,
    PropertyViewComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    SearchResultlistComponent,
    SearchResultComponent,
    ProfileSearchFormComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    ProfileViewComponent,
    ProfileEditComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    InquiriesComponent,
    InquiryItemComponent,
    PropertyEditComponent,
    InquiryItemFormComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    AccountViewComponent,
    AccountEditComponent,
    PasswordResetComponent,
    PasswordResetSendComponent,
    PasswordResetSubmitComponent,
    UserAuthentificationComponent,
    GlobalNotificationsDirective,
    SearchInfoWindowComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    TenantDetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.googleMapApiKey,
      libraries: ["places"]
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RecaptchaModule.forRoot(),
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ApiModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    InterceptorsModule,
    SharedModule,
    UserModule,
    [FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(), FroalaViewModule.forRoot()],
    [Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot()],
    DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    NgxIntlTelInputModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: { siteKey: environment.recaptchaSiteKey } as RecaptchaSettings
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Make sure you have added 'UploadComponent' in declarations of app.module.ts or some other module.

Comment: Yeah after posting here i looked in my app.module.ts and i forgot to add this component in it. But after adding in it i am getting another error. I updated above. Can you please look at it.

Comment: You cannot add declarations of same component,pipes, directives etc in multiple modules. i.e there must be only single declaration of component in your application. Hence according to your application, add it either in app.module.ts or shared.module.ts

Comment: Yes i agree but only adding in shared.module.ts i am getting of `'repo-upload' is not a known error.`

Comment: The shared.module.ts file is already imported in the app.module.ts file

Comment: Try writing 'UploadComponent' in exports array in addition of declaration array of SharedModule.

Comment: I treid with that and getting `Can't export directive UploadComponent from SharedModule as it was neither declared nor imported!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180728/discussion-between-sarthak-aggarwal-and-dev-tester).

Answer (score 0):

as per above data it looks that u haven't make entry of yours component in Module

1 add component entry to shared.module.ts (if you have) else entry should be in app.module.ts

2 don't forget to entry in  declaration : [ addComponentname ] Array

3 try with add component entry in both modules add.module.ts and shared.module.ts

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added it in the `shared.module.ts` file. Earlier i didn't added in the `app.module.ts` after adding in app.module.ts i am getting the error which updated in my question above.

Comment: can you please go through 3 option once

Comment: can you please post yours app.module.ts

Comment: In `shared.module.ts` the code is used as `import { UploadComponent } from './forms/image-upload/upload/upload.component';` and  `UploadComponent ` is added in `declarations` array. In app.module.ts I added  `import { UploadComponent } from './shared/forms/image-upload/upload/upload.component';` and getting the error which i updated in EDIT part

Comment: I updated my post with app.module.ts file. Have a look at it.

Comment: can you add component entry in both module (app and shared), i don't know but when i am using reCapthca module i solved by this way

Comment: When i am adding component in both ts files then i am getting error `Uncaught Error: Type UploadComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and AppModule! Please consider moving UploadComponent to a higher module that imports SharedModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes UploadComponent then import that NgModule in SharedModule and AppModule.`

Comment: okay remove it ..you sure you have urs component in shared.module.ts ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180729/discussion-between-bhagvat-lande-and-dev-tester).

Comment: Yes when creating component, shared.module.ts get updated automatically with the new component.